# Firestore: Document id of collection group's security rule becomes null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a simple security rule of a Collection group and the test code as following.

**Security rule:**

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /projects/{project_id}/members/{email} {
      allow write: if false;
    }
    match /{path=**}/members/{email} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  }
}
```

**Test code:**

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const firebase = require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing');
const MY_PROJECT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX';
const member1Data = {email: 'member1@gmail.com', name: 'John Smith'};
const member1Auth = {uid: "member1_uid", email: member1Data.email};

beforeEach(async () => {
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID});
  const db = firebase.initializeAdminApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID }).firestore();

  // create 2 same members data across projects
  await db.collection('projects/project-1/members')
    .doc(member1Data.email).set(member1Data);
  await db.collection('projects/project-2/members')
    .doc(member1Data.email).set(member1Data);
})

describe("Firestore rules test", () => {
  // 1 - direct access
  it( "Can get specific record", async () =>{
    const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: member1Auth }).firestore();
    const doc
      = await db.collection("projects/project-1/members").doc(member1Data.email);

    await firebase.assertSucceeds(doc.get());
  });
  // 2 - use collection group
  it( "Can get 2 records", async () =>{
    const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: member1Auth }).firestore();
    const result
      = await db.collectionGroup("members")
        .where("email", "==", member1Data.email).get();

    assert.strictEqual(result.size, 2);
  });
});
```

When I run the tests, the first one was passed but the second was failed.
After some research, I found out the variable `{email}` was **null** in the second test.

When I changed the rule to below ( change `email` to `resource.data.email`, all tests were passed.

```js
 :
match /{path=**}/members/{email} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email;
}
 :
```

So I wonder why the `{email}` variable is null only in the Collection group query.

Is this behavior written by documents?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your second test is not passing this `email`.

Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential result set instead of the actual field values for all of your documents.

The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the document. So when you're using the `resource.data.email`, you are narrowing down things to get an answer, that doesn't happen naturally with the `email` filter.

Here's the explanation of the differences: [Data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, I realized that I don't pass the `email` variable as **document ID**. But, one question, is there any way to give document ID to the rule using `collectionGroup()` method?

Comment: It's completely unclear why Firestore decided to make {email} null.  It's just a floating variable that can't be used.